# MS Word - Insert Text in worddocument after specified text

Tags: c#, ms-word

found several matches to my request, but not for word, so I open a new thread.
I got a word document. After a specified text, I want to insert some lines.

My code looks like that:

```
    public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string Filename = @"D:\...\MasterDoc.docx";
        string SearchFor = "Search this text and insert after it";
        string DocText = string.Empty;
        int InsertIndex = 0;

        //Run or attach MS Word
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wrdApp = RunOrAttachWordApplication();

        //Open masterfile
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(Filename);

        //Get complete range
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = doc.Range();

        //Get document text
        DocText = rng.Text;

        //Search indes to insert text
        InsertIndex = DocText.IndexOf(SearchFor) + SearchFor.Length;

        //Define range at location for text pasting
        rng = doc.Range(InsertIndex, InsertIndex + 1);

        //Write 'Test...' on specified location
        rng.InsertAfter("Test...");

        //Close document
        doc.Close(); /*Right here I got a breakpoint and watch the result, so I do not need to save the document here*/

        //Close application
        wrdApp.Application.Quit();
        wrdApp.Quit();
        wrdApp = null;

        System.GC.Collect();

        System.Console.WriteLine("Ende...");
        System.Console.ReadKey();

    }

    public static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application RunOrAttachWordApplication()
    {
        if(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Word").Length > 0)
        {
            return System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application") as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application;
        }
        else
        {
            return new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        }
    }
}
```

Well, it works - but not correctly. The text is inserted about 50 digits before the location, I want.

Does anybody know, how to fix that or I could imagine, that there is a much better methode to do that. I cannot modify the Masterdocument as it is recreated everytime by another, external program.

Thank you very much and regards,
Jan

Answer (score 1):

I find the [Find.Execute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.find.execute?view=word-pia) method much cleaner and shorter for adding/replacing text in the Word VSTO.

```
doc.Range().Find.Execute(FindText: SearchFor, Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceOne, ReplaceWith: SearchFor + " Test...");
```

It has many options, but for replacing the text I used:

```
 FindText - the text to find.
 Replace - how many replacements to make. [WdReplace][2] 
 ReplaceWith - the text.
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there is some metadata at the beginning of the file which is being ignored when you lookup the required index here:

`DocText.IndexOf(SearchFor) + SearchFor.Length;`

You can add the discrepancy to the insert, given that the amount is constant for all files:

```
//Search indes to insert text
InsertIndex = DocText.IndexOf(SearchFor) + SearchFor.Length + 50;
```

However, the most eloquent solution would be to stop using `rng.InsertAfter` and instead set `rng.Text` like this:

```
//Get document text
DocText = rng.Text;

//Search indes to insert text
InsertIndex = DocText.IndexOf(SearchFor) + SearchFor.Length;

//Update the text
DocText = DocText.Substring(0, InsertIndex) + "Test..." + DocText.Substring(InsertIndex);

// Set the new text
rng.Text = DocText;
```

Comment: Thank you. As there are some lines and stuff in the document, I followed the "less eloquent" solution, but it works perfect :)

Comment: I recommend using the more eloquent one because you do not know if that metadata will be the same on all Word documents. If the length changes, your code will break.

Answer (score 0):

Will unfortunatelly, the solution of EyIM does not work, as the textlength increased and its limited to 255 characters. Any other solutions? I really want to insert text, as there is some format in the document and I need to keep that.